# Why won't my bg image render in Next 13 app?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, sass, next.js13

I thought this was a relatively straightforward thing to do but apparently not. I have a bg image in a global scss file that does not wwant to render. It seems all of the other styles in the file are working and I don't belive the file paths are the problem but I could be wrong since the new app dir in Next 13 is throwing me for a loop.
Any help would be appreciated, below is my folder structure and also the scss causing issues.
[image]

I'll be happy to provide any other info as needed.

- Also i get this error in the dev tools console: p://localhost:3000/public/bg.jpg 404 (Not Found) in some layout.css file that i dont see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `public` in path to access assets in public folder. You can simply do it like `/bg.jpg` to access the `bg.jpg` image in public folder. Files inside public folder can be referenced with the base URL `/`.

I would still recommend you to keep all your images in an `images` folder and move that to an `assets` folder inside your `public` folder. Then you can access your images like this.
`/assets/images/bg.jpg`

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  What's funny is that if I tried referencing the image using the way that the other answer was given, I was getting another type of error even though it should still technically work. Regardless, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please reframe from posting screenshots of code as it makes it very difficult to help debug.

I believe the issue is that you are referencing the image inside the `styles` folder, but your image path isn't pointing to the right directory.

Because you provided no code in text form, I can't test it, but replacing your path with

```
../public/bg.jpg
```

should fix it.